# Deriving integrals of functions to obtain an ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, definite-integrals

A model for a population $P(t)$ is given by the integral equation

$$P'(t) = 2P(t) -2 \int_{0}^{t} P(s)ds -e^{2t},$$ where t represents time.

a) If you differentiate the integral equation you obtain an ordinary differential equation of second order (ODE). Determine this ODE.

Trying to derive it in chunks:

$$(2P(t))' = 2P'(t)$$
$$(-e^{2t})' = -2e^{2t}$$

But then...

$$\int_{0}^{t} P(s)ds = \; ?$$

There has to be some information in the proposition that I'm not taking advantage of I believe. How would one go about deriving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t P(s) \, ds = P(t)$$

by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Hence

$$P''(t)=2P'(t)-2P(t)-2e^{2t}$$